# Why I am getting Empty sym problem while solving the problem?

Tags: matlab, numeric, equation, solution

I want p as a function of x after solving this equation. I am unable to get a satisfoctory answer for this.

I am trying to get p as a function of x in MATLAB...bit, am getting an empty sym problem. How can I solve it numerically?

```
b=2.49*(10^(-10));
M=1.67;
T= 400;
D= 23*(10^(-6));
D_Cu= 2.88*(10^(-4))*exp(-32571.56/T);
D_Ni= 0.68*(10^(-4))*exp(-31392.83/T);
beta=4.7*(10^10);



%Darken's Equation
D_v= 0.647*D_Cu + 0.3196*D_Ni;
syms p x
 
eqn=5*10^8*x==-((2/b)*(sqrt(p)+(1/D)))+(5.58*(10^(15))*exp(-15.0234+150*b*sqrt(p))*p)/(44);

S=solve(eqn,p)
```

I just want a plot of p v/s s.

Comment: If all you want is a plot, why not solve for `x` instead of `p`? You’d have to deal with multiple solutions due to the square roots, but that’s not too hard.

Comment: Alternatively, the warning message from MATLAB directs you to [this help page](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/troubleshoot-equation-solutions-from-solve-function.html). Did you try the suggestions there?

Answer (score 0):

**1.- To plot multiple points are needed**

To plot any function you can either use 2 numerical vectors, or use a function that has to be defined in advance to attempting any plotting.

By using command solve in the way you do in the supplied lines, you are asking MATLAB to find the 1st root, MATLAB supplies a root, and stops.

With

```
eqn=5*10^8*x==-((2/b)*(sqrt(p)+(1/D)))+(5.58*(10^(15))*exp(-15.0234+150*b*sqrt(p))*p)/(44);

S=solve(eqn,x,p)
```

That returns 1 and only 1 point

```
S = 
  struct with fields:

    x: [1×1 sym]
    p: [1×1 sym]
S.x
 =
-12582083820137580698459643619347/18014398509481984000000000
double(S.x)
=
-6.9845e+05
S.p
 =
0
```

The inverse

```
S=solve(eqn,p,x)
```

also works. This I mention because from the question it's not clear if you are aiming at plotting `p(x)` or `x(p)`.

If you choose to use `solve` aiming at plotting then you have to iterate along a reference vector while compiling all obtained roots, which would be done with a `for` loop, for instance, that is not present in the code you have supplied.

I also tried with `T=400+273` just to make sure you are using the correct temperature value in your calculations.

**2.- plot with** `fplot`

Instead I suggest the following, for instance

```
f1=@(s) -((2/b)*(sqrt(s)+(1/D)))+(5.58*(10^(15))*exp(-15.0234+150*b*sqrt(s))*s)/(44);
fplot(f1)
grid on
xlabel('p')
```

[image]

But I doublt this is the graph you are really looking for, let me explain.

For those readers not familiar with these equations, [from here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darken%27s_equations), you tell us if this source is correct, Darken equations describe the solid-state diffusion of materials in binary solutions

2.1.- First Darken equation

[image]

2.2.- Second Darken equation

[image]

In both cases you need `N1` and `N2` and it's not clear if the expressions you use are really `N1` and `N2`.

If you are using the 1st equation, then where are the gradients of `N1` `N2` along `x`?

in this case it's not clear that the values you assign to `N1` and `N2` are really atomic fractions. Please correct or comment accordingly.

If you are using the 2nd equation, then where is `a1` the `activity coefficient` of the 1st component?

How do you decide which one is the 1st component?

By `S` in the question, do you mean the `D` with hat , the  overall difussivity?

I have the impression that you are lookging for a plot of  `D_hat(x)` , right?